# How to access images of local folder in project folder in Angular-cli

Tags: java, angular, rest, base64, angular-cli

I am trying to upload image through base64 and have uploaded the images in a folder on local. But after binding it in angular side, not able to access those images. AS I am working on Angular-cli, my component code is -
This code is for sending base64 string in backend after browsing image from UI-

```
base64:any;
url:any;
files : FileList; 
onSelectFile(event:any){
  console.log("onSelectFile",event);
  this.files = event.target.files;  
  console.log(this.files,"this.files");
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    this.currentFileUpload = this.files.item(0);
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
     reader.onload = (event:any) => {
      this.base64 = event.target.result;
      console.log(this.base64, this.url,"this.url......");
     }

  }
```

As I am using restful webservice in back-end so I convert base64 string to byte array and store the image in local folder. In response I am getting name of image. Below is the code for response -

```
getDataById(profileId: any) {     
    this.user.getDataById(profileId).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.data = response;
     this.url ="/home/aartek/Desktop/images"+this.data.profileImage;
     console.log(this.url);
    })
  }
```

My HTML code is-

```
<img [src]="url" height="150" width="150" class="img-circle mt20 ml-20">
```

In this HTML code I am trying to access the image from local folder path that I have given above in getDataById function.

I am getting this error:-

```
http://localhost:4200/home/aartek/Desktop/imagesMoon_merged_small.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You webservice in back-end should expose urls for those uploaded assets, so the clients (in this case, the client is your angular app) will access it using the http protocal (example: http://localhost:3000/uploaded/file1.jpg). It will not work the way you are trying to do, because the angular app won't have access to this unless (unless you bundle these folder with the files in build time).

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the URL to "./home/aartek/Desktop/images" + ...
2. Make sure that your folder with images is listed in the asset's property in .angular.cli, otherwise, it won't be included in the build.